# How to sort an itertools grouper array in python

Tags: python

I have the following itertools._grouper array of values

```
('a', 1L)
('c', 3L)
('b', 2L)
```

How would I go about sorting it so it is in the following order

```
('a', 1L)
('b', 2L)
('c', 3L)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is passing the right `key` parameter to the `sorted()` function. Try this:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Alternatively:

```
import operator as op
sorted(lst, key=op.itemgetter(1))
```

The above is assuming that `lst` is the input data, it doesn't matter where it comes from. Either way, the result will be as expected:

```
[('a', 1L), ('b', 2L), ('c', 3L)]
```

Comment: thanks! out of interest how would I reverse the order so c is first..?